# Sort and merge two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
[BA] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [num] => 55
                [val] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [num] => 41
                [val] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [num] => 65
                [val] => 27
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [num] => 60
                [val] => 28
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [num] => 70
                [val] => 90
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [num] => 78
                [val] => 113
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [num] => 85
                [val] => 119
            )

    )



[GE] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [num] => 76
                [val] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [num] => 26
                [val] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [num] => 69
                [val] => 11
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [num] => 64
                [val] => 48
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [num] => 9
                [val] => 85
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [num] => 36
                [val] => 112
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [num] => 90
                [val] => 127
            )

    )
```

I need to sort descending both the above two arrays by "val" and merge them into one array like the following:

```
 [new] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'GE'
                    [num] => 90
                    [val] => 127
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'BA'
                    [num] => 85
                    [val] => 119
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'BA'
                    [num] => 78
                    [val] => 113
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'GE'
                    [num] => 36
                    [val] => 112
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'BA'
                    [num] => 70
                    [val] => 90
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'GE'
                    [num] => 9
                    [val] => 85
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [ruota] => 'GE'
                    [num] => 64
                    [val] => 48
                )

        )
```

Please, could someone help me?
Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: In what way shall they be merged, so that the desired result contains only half of the original data?

Comment: @Armali merge them, sort them by "val" and return only the first 6.

Comment: You mean: the first 7.

Comment: @Armali yes, because it's 0-based

Answer (score 2):

The is a very simple task that can be achieved with a simple loop (Don't be afraid of loops)

**Step 1 :  Merge and Pad Array**

```
// Merge Both arrays
$array = $ba + $ge; // or array_merge($ba,$ge);

// New Array
$new = [];

// Start Loop to pad array
foreach($array as $ruota => $var) {
    foreach($var as $v) {
        $v['routa'] = $ruota; // add routa to each element
        $new[] = $v;
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Sort and Output array**

```
// Sort Values
usort($new, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['val'] - $a['val']; // Sort Decending
});

// Output Result
print_r($new);
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33170)

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding the key to each array, e.g. something like:

```
foreach (array($ba, $ge) as &$array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => &$values) {
    foreach ($values as &$value) {
      $value['ruota'] = $key;
    }
  }
}
```

Then merge, e.g.:

```
$values = array_merge(array_values($ba), array_values($ge));
```

Then sort, e.g.:

```
usort($values, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['val'] == $b['val']) {
        return 0;
  }
  return ($a['val'] < $b['val']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Note: there might be an error or two in the above, but it should put you on the right track.